# Only select max minute DateDiff on duplicate rows, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, datediff

I have two tables, TableA has columns: Job, Machine, CutStart, CutEnd. TableB has columns:job, Start, End. Table A has a primary key of job and machine. TableB has a primary key of job. Essentially, tableB is where all the stuff from multiple machines from tableA come together. I need to pull the LONGEST time difference between tableA.CutStart to tableB.End. Since there are multiple machines associated with a single job I am getting multiple differences in minutes associated to each job, and I need to select only the largest one. Here is my code so far. Also, please note that the job is in the form of a smalldatetime. There are also some other various where statement to remove bad data.

```
SELECT tableA.Job, DateDiff(MINUTE, tableA.cutstart, tableB.end) as 'total minute'
From tableA
left join tableB on
tableA.Job = tableB.Job
where tableA.Job >= '2016-02-01' AND tableA.Job <= (DATEADD(Month, 1, '2016-02-01'))
AND datediff(Minute, tableA.cutstart, tableB.end) < 17280 AND datediff(Minute, tableA.cutstart, tableB.End) > 20
group by tableA.Job, tableA.CutStart, tableB.End order by tableA.Job
```

An Example.
Table A has jobs A and B with 3 different machines on each with their own individual cutstart and cut end. Table B has only jobs A and B with a single start and end for each. If you run the code above you get 6 results and I only want 2. The 2 results being the time difference with the largest gap between tableA.cutstart and tableB.end.

--------------UPDATE-----------

TableA

```
Job   Machine            CutStart              CutEnd
A         5           2016-02-03 08:56      2016-02-03 10:50
A         6           2016-02-03 07:32      2016-02-03 9:42
A         7           2016-02-03 09:12      2016-02-03 11:15
B         5           2016-02-03 08:56      2016-02-03 10:50
B         6           2016-02-03 08:56      2016-02-03 10:50
B         7           2016-02-03 08:56      2016-02-03 10:50
```

TableB

```
Job      Start                 End
A      2016-02-03 13:53       2016-02-03 15:32
B      2016-02-03 13:53       2016-02-03 15:32
```

Current Results

```
Job      "Minute difference"
A              54
A             112
A               96
B             154
B             93
B             217
```

Desired results

```
Job      "Minute difference"
A             112
B             217
```

I only want to select the longest minuet difference on each job. Also, The numbers dont add up they are just place holders.

----------------------Final Solution------------------

```
SELECT tableB.Job, DateDiff(MINUTE, (
  SELECT MIN(tableA.cutstart) 
  FROM tableA
  WHERE tableA.Job=tableB.Job
), tableB.end) as [total minute]
From tableB
where {whatever conditions you want}
```

Comment: Not really sure what the question is here. But why are you using DATEADD with a date literal? Why not just '2016-03-01'??

Comment: @SeanLange that where statement is returning all dates between Feb. 1, 2016 and Mar. 1, 2016. The job is in the form of a smalldatetime and that line you are looking at is selecting all jobs in the month of February. I am just using dateadd to run that date up one month. It is returning values for me.

Comment: @SeanLange in short I could change that line to tableA.job >= '2016-02-01' AND TableA.job <= '2016-03-01'

Comment: I have updated for more clarity

Comment: I understand what it is doing but it seems pointlessly complicated to use dateadd to add a month to a date literal. Unless of course you are using a parameter in your actual query and you used a literal in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to think like a SQL Developer:

"I need to pull the LONGEST..."

Translates to:

"I need the top 1, ordered by..."

So something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tableA.Job, DateDiff(MINUTE, tableA.cutstart, tableB.end) as [total minute]
From tableA
left join tableB on
tableA.Job = tableB.Job
where {whatever conditions you want)
ORDER BY DateDiff(MINUTE, tableA.cutstart, tableB.end) DESC
```

EDIT:   If you want the longest run time for each job, the answer is even easier to think about.

The job only has one end time, so the longest run for each job is going to be whichever joining row in tableA has the earliest start time.

Here's one way to get that (there are many):

```
SELECT tableB.Job, DateDiff(MINUTE, (
  SELECT MIN(tableA.cutstart) 
  FROM tableA
  WHERE tableA.Job=tableB.Job
), tableB.end) as [total minute]
From tableB
where {whatever conditions you want}
```

Just be careful to put conditions relating to TableB in the main WHERE clause, and conditions relating to TableA in the subquery.

Comment: I tried doing a select top 1 but it doesn't work because it is only selecting the top 1 line item in my query. This table has many jobs. Each job is being duplicated per the amount of machines that job has ran on. Therefore each job could have 3 to 5 different machines on tableA. I need the longest datediff for each job.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your clarification.

Comment: I had no idea you could run a select statement inside a datediff. The data still copied itself but its nothing a SELECT DISTINCT couldn't take care of. thanks

Comment: As long as a sub-select can only return a single value, it can be used anywhere in a SQL statement where a single value is expected.